# Python: Project Package / Module structure dependency Problem

Tags: python

I was hoping someone could help me figure out an odd "dependency" problem.  I have a fairly large python project, with a slimmed down structure that looks like:

```
Sitka
│   DataTickers.py
│   example.csv
│   FinDates.py
│   SitkaMongo.py
│   tickers_csv.csv
│   __init__.py
│
├───Fin
│   │   main.py
│   │   md_provider_control.py
│   │   Tofino.py
│   │   __init__.py
│   │
│   │
│   ├───Instruments
│   │   │   market_standard_instruments.py
│   │   └   __init__.py
│   │   
│   ├───Env
│   │   │   CurveClass.py
│   │
│   ├───Utils
│       │   charting.py
│       │   exchange_identifier_mapper.py
│       │   fin_mapper.py
│       │   md_provider_simulation.py
│       └   __init__.py
```

##### Tofino.py:

```
from .Env.CurveClass import CurveData as _CurveData

class Tofino():    
       
    def __init__(self, mdp, VAL_ENV = None):
        
        mdp.tofino = self  # link Tofino 
       
        # Public VE Refernce
        self.val_env = VAL_ENV
        self.ir_config = VAL_ENV.market
```

##### market_standard_instruments.py:

```
# Standard Imports
import Sitka.FinDates as fdate 
import datetime as dt
import re
from itertools import product

# bunch of functions after this.
```

##### CurveClass.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

class CurveData():
    def __init__(self):
        self.do_stuff= self._stuff()
```

##### main.py

```
from Sitka.FinDates import getMainDates

# Sitka- Custom Imports
from .md_provider_control import MD_ProviderV3
from .Tofino import Tofino
import Sitka.Fin.Instruments.market_standard_instruments as mkt_std

def main() -> Tofino:
    #  < ---- do a bunch of stuff ---- >    

    return Tofino(mdp = mdp, VAL_ENV=ve.GLOBAL_VALN_ENV)
```

##### And lastly, Sitka.Fin.__ init __.py:

```
import logging
import traceback

# Run Valuation Environment Startup
from .main import main

# Global Variables:
from .Tofino import Tofino  as _Tofino
 
tofino : _Tofino
tofino = None
try:    
    tofino = main()    # I was trying some stuff out here, hence the weird traceback in try
except:
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

My issue is, after all that, is when I run `import Sitka.Fin as fin`, this line in main.py

```
import Sitka.Fin.Instruments.market_standard_instruments as mkt_std
```

fires off the `Sitka.Fin__init__` process again before we even get to the try block (so init basically runs 2x).

Any help is appreciated!

P.S.  Basically I'm just including subfolder **init**'s because its the only way I know how to get Intellsense/autocomplete in the IDE to work nicely...  I would love to know how to make my code 'cleaner' from that sense.

##### Edit:

A simpler way to look at the problem. Lets say I open a new IPython console, and only do:

```
import Sitka.Fin.Instruments.market_standard_instruments as mkt_std
```

Simply doing this kicks off the entire `Sitka.Fin.__init__` procedure [which I wouldn't have expected]

Answer (score 1):

It seems you only want some code of the `main.py` to run when the file itself is running. Try using:

```
if __name__ in "__main__": # All sikta imports
    from Sitka.FinDates import getMainDates
    from .md_provider_control import MD_ProviderV3
    from .Tofino import Tofino
    import Sitka.Fin.Instruments.market_standard_instruments as mkt_std
```

Comment: so I generally am using IPython to run things.  So I dont really run a 'script' persay

Comment: Sorry - I should also add.  the main() function requires all the imports in main.py [maybe I should name the file differently....]

Comment: I think this would work perfectly fine.

Comment: I also still dont understand, given my imports in main.py, why it would cause Sitka.Fin__init__ to kick off

Comment: I tried to throw all the imports into the main() function.  Didn't solve the issue

Comment: Do you mind pushing your code into [GitHub](https://www.github.com) and sending the repo. Maybe there's an issue somewhere else.

Comment: unfort can't blocked... [and I had to edit the .py's down a ton to start as well]

Comment: Maybe another way to look at the problem.  Lets say I open a new IPython console, and *only* do:  import Sitka.Fin.Instruments.market_standard_instruments as mkt_std.     Simply doing this kicks off the entire Sitka.Fin.__init__ procedure [which I wouldn't have expected]

Comment: `__init__` is meant to run whenever the parent function/class is called. Simply change that name and I think it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, change what name?

Comment: You have `__init__.py` files. I would suggest you to change the names.